# Using -B option blocks interpreter

Tags: php, linux, shell, command-line

When trying to execute PHP interpreter from Linux shell, with the -B option, the supplied begin_code is executed but the process blocks and the main script (`f2.php`) is not executed.

Problem reproduction:

```
$ php -v
PHP 8.1.13 (cli) (built: Nov 22 2022 14:42:07) (NTS gcc x86_64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.13, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.13, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
$ cat f2.php 
<?php
 echo "f2 running.\n";
?>
$ php f2.php 
f2 running.
$ php  -B 'echo "init\n";' f2.php 
init
```

And the shell blocks. I must then use ctrl+C to return to prompt.
I expected that the script `f2.php` is also executed.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `-B` argument, PHP enters interactive mode. To execute `f2.php`, you need to add the `-F` parameter but then it will only run your script after you hit the ENTER key:

```bash
me:~$ php -B 'echo "init\n";' -F f2.php
init
<ENTER>
f2 running.
<ENTER>
f2 running.
^C
me:~$
```

To "trick" PHP into non-interactive mode, pipe something into the `php` command. PHP will then run the init code and your script, and then terminate:

```bash
me:~$ echo | php -B 'echo "init\n";' -F f2.php
init
f2 running.
me:~$
```

Comment: Combining the piped 'echo' with the -F option makes perfectly what was I looking for.   Thank for solution.